# getting all messages to one consumer in one group of kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new in learning Kafka. I am trying to get messages in different consumer of same group but am getting message in only one consumer second consumer got 0 messages. I am running two broker at 9092 and 9093.
created one topic name test2 with replication-factor 2 and partition 2
`kafka-topics.bat --create --topic test2 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 2 --           replication-factor 2`
now started 2 consumers

```
`kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test2 --group test2group"`
```

same command for 2 consumers

Then started producer

```
`kafka-console-producer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test2`
```

and started sending messages

Trying to change replication-factor and partitions also but didnt work

Comment: Simply produce more data to create new batches which may go to other partitions. You do not need two brokers since replication isn't the problem here